# Parse log file with spaces

Tags: vb.net, parsing, datagridview, logfile, logfile-analysis

I am trying to parse a `logfile` (text file saved as a `*.log` file) into Visual Basic 2013 Express' `DataGridView`. The log file uses spaces as its delimiter, but the message part of the log has spaces in it.  Here is the layout of the log file:

> Date Time ID Connection Type_of_message(command/response/status/etc)
>   Message(may include a number of spaces (not the same amount of spaces
>   per message))

Each log entry is a separate line in the file.

**EDIT:** Here is [an example of the log file](http://pastebin.com/wyEVwda3#):

```
2014-02-03 15:35:29 9900 3 Status: Listing directory [[server folder]]
2014-02-03 15:35:46 9900 3 Status: Invalid character sequence received, disabling UTF-8. Select UTF-8 option in site manager to force UTF-8.
2014-02-03 15:35:46 9900 3 Status: Calculating timezone offset of server...
2014-02-03 15:35:46 9900 3 Command: mtime "[[file name]]"
2014-02-03 15:35:46 9900 3 Response: 1382557913
2014-02-03 15:35:46 9900 3 Status: Timezone offsets: Server: -14400 seconds. Local: -18000 seconds. Difference: -3600 seconds.
2014-02-03 15:36:18 9900 2 Status: Connected to [[server name]]
2014-02-03 15:36:18 9900 1 Status: Starting upload of [[local folder name/file name (includes 3 spaces)]]
2014-02-03 15:36:18 9900 1 Command: cd "[[server folder]]"
2014-02-03 15:36:18 9900 2 Status: Starting upload of [[local folder name/file name (includes 3 spaces)]]
2014-02-03 15:36:18 9900 1 Response: New directory is: "[[server folder]]"
2014-02-03 15:36:18 9900 1 Command: put "[[local folder name/file name (includes 2 spaces)]]"
2014-02-03 15:36:18 9900 2 Command: cd "[[server folder]]"
2014-02-03 15:36:18 9900 1 Status: local: [[local folder name/file name (includes 3 spaces)]]=> remote:[[server folder]]
```

Comment: Just ignore spaces between brackets

Comment: Aside from space being the delimiter, what's the format of your log file? Give several lines as an example.

Comment: @Neolisk I just edited my question with a link to an example of my log files.

Comment: Always try to include all relevant information in the question, with no external links. See my edit. Other than that - check my answer - I think that's what you need.

Comment: @Neolisk Sorry, I didn't think the logs were able to post as nicely as they did for you, or I would have.

Answer (score 2):

It may not be pretty, but it works:

```
Dim line As String = "2014-02-03 15:35:29 9900 3 Status: Listing directory [[server folder]]"
Dim split As String() = line.Split(" "c)
Dim message As String = String.Join(" "c, split.Skip(5).ToArray)
```

This is assuming you have 6 columns in total, and the last one is your message.

**EDIT:** As suggested by @Andrew Morton, the split can be rewritten (no LINQ):

```
Dim split As String() = line.Split({" "c}, 6, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Comment: Or `Dim parts = line.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), 5, StringSplitOptions.None)` using one of the [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131450%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overloads.

Comment: That is correct, I plan to have only 6 columns. I will give your script a try.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: I was originally looking for this overload, but VS did not suggest it to me, so I thought I may have remembered something wrong. Thanks for mentioning - included in the EDIT.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Looking over the script I was already using, I had nearly the same attributes already in the split, except for the number (which is 6, not 5)

`For Each col As String In txtlines(rows).Split({delimiter}, 6, StringSplitOptions.None)`

Comment: @CampSoup1988: This is why you should always provide source code in your question. 5 or 6 depends on whether you want to keep message type as part of the message itself.